# Issue with mod_rewrite (possibly related to special characters?)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect, redirect

We have just made a new website for a client and for SEO purposes have a HUGE urlmap setup to rewrite the old site URLs to relevant places on the new site.

Technical details are:

```
CentOS 5.6 
Apache 2.2
mod_rewrite
PHP 5.3.8
```

Here is the mod_rewrite block:

```
RewriteMap urls txt:/www/sites/domain.co.uk/etc/urlmap.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${urls:%1|NONE} ^(.*)?$
RewriteCond %1  !NONE
RewriteRule .*  %1 [R=301,NS,QSA,L]
```

Some redirects do work, for example:

**www.domain.co.uk/store/SEURLF/ASP/SFS/PP.Y/RID.577/SFE/Diaries.htm** redirects correctly.

**www.domain.co.uk/store/SEURLF/ASP/SFS/CATID.1/FORMAT.STUDENT%2FSCHOOL+WEEK+TO+VIEW/ACADEMIC.1/SFE/diaries.htm** does not, and 404s. The only difference here is the "+" symbols. This doesn't appear in the rewrite log either, like it's being completely passed over by mod_rewrite due to the special characters.

Another odd occurrence is, for example:

**www.domain.co.uk/store/diaries.asp?catid=3** - doesn't rewrite properly, looking in the Apache rewrite log it's completely ignoring the query "**?catid=3**" for some reason.

I am no expert on mod_rewrite so would appreciate any assistance. If you need more information please do ask.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Fixed with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\?%{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${urls:%1|NONE} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %1  !NONE
RewriteRule .*  %1? [R=301,NS,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule pattern (and `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable) can ONLY match path part of the URL. To match query string you have to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} YOUR_PATTERN_HERE`. For special characters -- try using `[B]` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Thanks for that. Got it going with an additional rule which I've added as an edit to my question.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so others can stop reading the full question before realizing it's been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\?%{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${urls:%1|NONE} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %1  !NONE
RewriteRule .*  %1? [R=301,NS,L]
```

Thanks guys.